# web-to-lead contact form

Tags: contact, web2lead

I've set up a web-to-lead contact form in order to sync contact requests from the website with Salesforce CRM. The sync works fine: the filled fields from the website are showed in the CRM. I need to set up a verification check (all the fields are required). To tho this, I've used a javascript-injected submit. When a user fill the fields and then submit the form, here is the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed access.

Origin '' stands for "http://domainname.ext", obviously.

Answer (score 4):

You are hitting the browser's same origin security policy.  This means that your JavaScript can only make AJAX calls back to the same origin of the containing page - in this case http://domainname.ext.  You are trying to make an AJAX call to Salesforce and that gets blocked.

CORS (cross origin resource sharing) relaxes this restriction by letting servers define which origins are allowed to call them through HTTP headers such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin. However, this is configured on the target server (www.salesforce.com) so Salesforce would need to provide these headers in response to your request, and they don't. Thus your request doesn't succeed and the browser gives you the error.

What is a little confusing about CORS is that you make a request to the server and it will respond with headers to indicate whether the request was allowed or not.  The browser then tells you that you can't access that server, but it didn't know until you tried!

Update: [See Use CORS to Access Supported Salesforce APIs, Apex REST, and Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think Bob is spot on (though his response is beyond my technical skill-set).

I will add that the standard Salesforce Web to Lead is designed to be very 'dumb', in the sense that it never rejects any leads. It will take practically any incoming lead submission unless it breaks your validation rules, in which case you'll get an email from Salesforce. So almost all errors will be on the javascript / browser side.

You might want to look at the myriad of form submission add-ons. There's free plugins for [Wordpress][1] as well as most other CMS's, plus paid form submission tools (like FormAssembly) and paid landing pages (like Unbounce) that will accomplish the validation and other checks. These also hide your OID, which is handy as once spammers know that they can bypass your validation and submit to Salesforce directly.

Comment: Stony - read up over here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/behavior - your sig line and product promotion are both out of line and will earn you down-votes. Your first 2 paras are a decent answer - if you edit and remove the offending material, I, at least, would reverse my vote.