# What does same origin policy mean when trying to submit a Web to lead form via AJAX?

Tags: ajax, web2lead, cors

I am stuck working on a task, I get a same origin policy error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8'
> from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I saw some answers on the subject, like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28262/web-to-lead-contact-form), but I felt the answer is complicated since I did not pay too much attention to such problems before, I want to understand what is happening inside !

Will my problem dispappear If I submit the form from a different domain, if Yes ? Then what type of domain will be accepted and why ?

I know that for example that my form will be submitted from a domain `www.enx.com` ( production ), This is salesforce link for example `https://enx.lightning.force.com` ( I know it is stupid to share this :) but no longer know what is this )

What I tried is allowing localhost in Salesforce Setup and trying to submit the form locally and got this error!

Also Can I move to a backend language to help with this more ?

EDIT : -----------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried to do the submission via a local php script, this script is going to be consumed by my frontend form, but still not working!

I know it is not working because I have the default form ( with default submission ) & this curl post submission, when i submit the defualt form, I see leads being created, when I send data via php, I get null as a repsonse, even tho the same fields are being used :

```
<?php

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data){
                echo "there is data \n";
                var_dump($data);
                echo "\n";
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
    return $result;
}

$dis = CallAPI(
    "POST",
    "https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
        [
            "first_name" => "enixa test of testings", 
            "email" => "b.taoufiq@pulse.digital",
            "oid" => "00D09000002Z7xf",
            "retURL" => "https://www.kooora.com"
        ]
);

?>
```

This is my default form :

```
<html>

<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Web to lead</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
    <!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
    <!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->



    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

    <form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

        <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D09000002Z7xf">
        <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.kooora.com">

        <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
        <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
        <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
        <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
        <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
        <!--  value="jocelyn.gross@isobar.com">                                       -->
        <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

        <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20"
            type="text" /><br>

        <label for="email">Email</label><input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>



</body>

</html>
```

I really will appreciate an explanation or help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is CORS?

A cross-origin resource sharing request occurs when JavaScript from domain A attempts to contact domain B. This occurs even when domain A and domain B are both subdomains under domain C.

## Why is this restricted?

A malicious actor could inject JavaScript into a webapp on domain A to steal sensitive data (passwords, session IDs, credit card info, etc) to send to domain B. This is an XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attack. To combat XSS, scripts from domain A must get permission to contact domain B, which adds at least a minimal level of security for domain A.

## How is this enforced?

This is enforced by all major browsers, and consists of a "pre-flight" request. This request contacts the domain B server asking if domain A can send data to it. If domain B explicitly allows it, the script from domain A is allowed to continue.

## How can I fix it?

Only the owner/controller of the servers for domain B. Since salesforce.com operates these servers, and they've deemed it a security/privacy risk to allow CORS, web-to-lead doesn't allow this access. Changing the domain you're using won't fix the problem.

Since you can't fix it, the alternative solution is to use a proxy server that you do control. This might be the same site that you're developing, or a proxy that specifically allows CORS by adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and then having that service forward the request to salesforce.com's server for processing.

Comment: Proxy server ? I can for example send data to a server & that server is the one that will communicate with salesforce ? like a hosted php script ? something like this ?

Comment: @TaouBen Yes. That's the defacto standard for web2lead scripts that use JavaScript (not necessarily PHP, any language will work, but you've got the idea).

Comment: So excuse my stupidity but this will work for local php script for example or it has to hosted ?? because I have created a script, I still don't know how is it validated but I am redirected to the return url ? what do you think ? & By the way Thanks for the exxplanation above, i understood how we are escaping those restrictions using an intermediate server

Comment: @TaouBen A server needs to execute the PHP script (browsers can't call PHP directly), but that can be an IIS, Apache, Express, etc server hosted locally (localhost). Web-to-Lead does not validate the input immediately, it is queued for later processing. As such, you should always get back a success message and redirect to the return URL, if specified.

Comment: I tried with Apache server, I sent data via curl post, I got redirected to the return url, I dont see the leads yet, I will wait I think.. I think that means success

Comment: @TaouBen As long as the org ID is correct, it should appear. It is asynchronous, so it may take a few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120089/discussion-between-taouben-and-sfdcfox).